# how do i share files between windows computers on a local network?

Tags: windows-vista, router, home-networking, file-management, file-sharing

We are trying to set up a home network where all computers can see shared files on all other computers.

So far we've got two computers connected via a wireless router/modem, connected via ethernet cables. Both computers are running windows vista.

Computer A can see all the shared files on computer B.

Computer B can't see the shared files on computer A. Computer B see that computer A is on the network, in network map. But computer B can't ping computer A.

A and B are in the same workgroup, and on the same network.

Comment: I would say it's a firewall issue, check the firewall settings on computer A

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have a problem with either file and printer sharing or network discovery. Make sure they are both turned on both machines. You can find out how to access those settings here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/enable-file-and-printer-sharing .You can also turn off your firewall on computer A.