# Windows 10 file sharing not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares

I'm trying to share folders on my laptop with my workstation computer.  Both computers are running Windows 10 Professional.  In the Network view, both computers can see each other, but there's no access.  They can access their own shares though.  I run the troubleshooter and it says that the other computer does not respond.  The laptop has WiFi disabled and is connected via ethernet cable.

- Both computers are connected to the same switch.
- Both computers are assigned IP addresses in the same subnet.
- Both computers have the other in the ARP routing table.
- I can ping the computers from each other.
- IPv6 is disabled on both computers.
- Both computers have ethernet configured as private.
- Both computers are members of the same workgroup.
- SMB 1.0 is installed on both computers.
- When opening the Network window, I can see both computers.
- In the Network window, access to the other computer gives an error
  that it's not responding.
- The folders are properly shared.
- The firewall has file/printer sharing allowed.
- The firewall has directSMB allowed.
- NetBIOS over TCP/IP is enabled.
- Both computers have no problems accessing the internet.

I have also tried the procedures listed in the following websites:

https://www.ubackup.com/synchronization/windows-10-file-sharing-not-working-6988.html
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-10-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf)
https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/fix-windows-10-file-sharing-not-working.html#1
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-file-sharing-is-not-working-in-windows

I have also looked at these following SO questions as well:

[Network File Sharing no longer working after upgrade to Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1013406/network-file-sharing-no-longer-working-after-upgrade-to-windows-10)
[Can't connect to my Windows 10 File Sharing Server](https://superuser.com/questions/1265763/cant-connect-to-my-windows-10-file-sharing-server?rq=1)
[how do i share files between windows computers on a local network?](https://superuser.com/questions/624097/how-do-i-share-files-between-windows-computers-on-a-local-network?rq=1)

At this point, I am at a loss as to what to do.  Everything checks out and they they refuse to talk to each other.  This did work once before, but I'm not sure what changed.
In any case, I really need this to work.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

- All involved accounts are local accounts.

I have made an interesting discovery.  If I use the IP address, I can map a share to a drive letter....

net use * \\<IP Address>\<Share Name>

But if I use the computer name that shows up in the computer browser, it gives me a system error 53.  I can use the IP address in Explorer to map a network drive as well, but I can't use the name.  So something else is going on.  I wonder if I have to configure a WINS server on the network to provide name resolution, or allow computer to register their DNS information in my DNS server (ISC BIND on FreeBSD, with DHCP).

Comment: SMBv1 should be disabled and removed from the PC via `optionalfeatures` as it's actively exploited daily and is insecure _(all OSes have supported SMBv2+ for over a decade)_; SMB Direct should be enabled. Are the workgroup names the same on both? Ports required: UDP: `137`, `138`, `139` | TCP: `139`, `445`. If wanting to access by hostname only, please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1467884/529800).

Comment: The computers need to be both on local accounts, or both on Microsoft accounts, for the sharing to work.

Comment: You could install Wireshark on both pcs. Needs some learning, but will help to solve most problems.

Comment: @JW0914 I wondered about the hostname lookup.  Besides, I made a very interesting discovery about that.  I'll update the question with more information...